# Save php web info to an excel spreadsheet

Tags: php

Ok we have this prefilled excel spreadsheet that we just update our name, mileage, and location on once a month.  The spreadsheet calculates our millage with the built in formulas. What I would like to do is have this page on our website. I would pull from a sql database depending on the options you select prefill my labels on the web and save it to the correct spot on the excel spreadsheet once submitted. Sounds easy in theory but I'm not sure how to go about doing this or if it is even possible? Can someone help me out or get me started in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: does it really need to be written back to an excel spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [PHPExcel](http://www.phpexcel.net). It allows you to read and write Excel documents (and PDFs, and OpenOffice.org Calc documents and more).